# primary key name is required field?

Tags: sql-server, constraints

Is there any difference between the below 2 CREATE TABLE statements in SQL Server 200x/2012? I generated this script from two different tables, one had a Key name defined (PK_Table1) whereas the other had some kind of randomly generated number associated to it (PK_Table1_1084F446).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    <<Other Column declaration here>>
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
Few more non-clustered indexes declaration here


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    <<Other Column declaration here>>
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
Few more non-clustered indexes declaration here
```

Comment: The only difference is that you specified a name for the constraint in the second create table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the same way, but natural names are more convenient:

1) when altering constraint you can easy refer to it (if you gave sensible name);

2) when query failed due to constraint, name of this constraint is showed, so you can easily know what cause an error (if you gave sensible name).